# MPMoviePlayerViewController play from NSData (MP4)

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsdata, mp4

```
NSString *p = [app getFilePathFor:name];
// Printing description of p:
// /Users/Jackson/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7FE97EDD-D080-4E5E-8EDD-3D9FFA8F6CF5/Documents/6681a4d7-8630-4a12-90c6-f95d72650a42

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:p];
// Printing description of data:
// <01401dc2 a15ebc27 e473ee79 316568ff 19dc7000 df3f7c5c dc206870 01a1c00e 00010000 00000000 00e10288 00000003 01060020 08c80038 00080000 88edffbf 02000119 0000050e 00000000 00000000 02000007 0000050f 00000000 00000000>

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// Printing description of str:
// @Â¡^¼'äsîy1ehÿÜp

path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];
// Printing description of path:
// %01@%1D%C3%82%C2%A1%5E%C2%BC'%C3%A4s%C3%AEy1eh%C3%BF%19%C3%9Cp%00%C3%9F%3F%7C%5C%C3%9C%20hp%01%C2%A1%C3%80%0E%00%01%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%C3%A1%02%C2%88%00%00%00%03%01%06%00%20%08%C3%88%008%00%08%00%00%C2%88%C3%AD%C3%BF%C2%BF%02%00%01%19%00%00%05%0E%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%02%00%00%07%00%00%05%0F%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00 -- file://localhost/
```

Then I send the path to the MPMoviePlayerViewController like so:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController * playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:path];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:(MPMoviePlayerViewController *)playerController];

playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[playerController.moviePlayer play];
playerController=nil;
```

At this point, the Movie Player shows, then immediate hides once the "show" animation is complete. In the log I get this:

```
An instance 0x87ca7b0 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x87dfc30> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x933c280: Observer: 0x93367d0, Key path: nonForcedSubtitleDisplayEnabled, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x933c630>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x933c360: Observer: 0x93356b0, Key path: presentationSize, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x87b53b0>
```

I have no idea where to go next.. *help?*

** EDIT **

the MP4 I'm trying to play is coming from [this buckbunny test clip](http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4). When I load the clip straight in form the URL it works. But if I download it and save it via NSData and try to reopen the NSData this no longer works.

** EDIT 2 **

@Till: "You are initializing a URL with a string that is garbledegock; `// str=@"@Â¡^¼'äsîy1ehÿÜp" path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];` What are you expecting here?"

So now that I've tried:

```
path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[app getFilePathFor:name]];
// Printing description of path:
// file://localhost/Users/Jackson/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/CB1CA8D0-B5EC-4B5F-8C7F-0EF449508BA7/Documents/9d425856-14b0-4ad3-835a-970affacb05f
```

I'm still getting the EXACT same error.

Comment: You are initializing a URL with a string that is garbledegock; // `str=@"@Â¡^¼'äsîy1ehÿÜp"` 
`path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];`
What are you expecting here?

Comment: @Till I added `EDIT 2` directed at your comment, and I'm still stuck..

Comment: Did you try removing the code where you are releasing the player pointer?
playerController=nil;
?

Comment: @Lefteris Yes, but I still got the same error. My hypothesis is that the player loads up and sees that it's getting a bad request so it closes. Consequently more player related code is still looking for the player and can't find it so it dispatches that log. That's my best guess anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you converting to nsdata from the saved clip file?

You should just load the path for the clip in your app documents directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

yourMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: fileURL];
```

Comment: I'm finally getting a valid filename back with your method, but I still get this same lame error. Could it have something to do with the way I'm storing?

Comment: It WAS do to the was I was storing it. The 5MB file was only being stored as one of the 1KB slices because I was doing it wrong. What's I got it right, your method of loading worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the fact that you are setting it to `nil` while it's playing. Actually, it appears that it happens so quickly that the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is still loading the material when you set it to `nil`.