# Using NSData with MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsdata

I am trying to use NSData with MPMoviePlayerViewController.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:mData3->mappedAddress+100398125 length:2313453 freeWhenDone:NO];

NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataString];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
```

This leads to the player opening for a second and then being dismissed.

When I access the movie file locally using the URL to the file in the main bundle it plays perfectly.

How does one use NSData to play a video on iOS?

Thanks

Comment: Are you downloading the clip from the Internet? If yes, why don't you save it first and then open it as a file ?

Comment: No. The file is mapped to virtual memory

Comment: OK, but where is originating from then? from the phone ?

Comment: Yes. The virtual memory of the phone. I know a similar issue exists with mp3 files in NSData with AVAudioPlayer where the file header actually causes AVAudioPlayer to mishandle the file, but using the same mp3 with a NSURL works fine. Maybe it is a similar issue here.

Comment: I'm asking because if the file is stored in the app's sandbox directory you can simply load it as a file, as [I showed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10377158/312312)

Comment: I know thank you. I did that to confirm the file works. That is not what I am after though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to play a movie directly from an in-memory NSData blob.